# Android post image using intent and html with phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, android-intent

How I get image to html file, where you also write description about that and post that to web server? Using this code to get action from Share in gallery. Also got intent code in manifest.xml

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND))
    {
        Uri data = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM); 
        if (data != null) {
        data.toString();            
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/i2.html#" + data);
        }
    }
```

That loads url and data is image path. But JS doesn't allow to put value to input type="file" so i need another way to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, couple of issues here.

1. You can't pre-populate the value of input type file. Why? What if someone created a hidden file input, pre-populated it with ~/mypasswords.txt and uploaded it without you knowing? This is an obvious security risk and no decent, half-way respecting browser would allow it.
2. If data is the url to the image, then within your html source code, you can write some javascript which will parse the document's URL in order to get the url and create / set an img element's src attribute to display the image.
3. If you wish to then upload the image to a server somewhere else on the (real) internet (eg, not to local assets but to a live server), then you will have to create a clickable input of type file and have the user select the image themselves. Do you users a service by saving your image file to an easily accessible location such as the root of the SD card or even their images/pictures or downloads folder, and then direct them to upload the correct image -- you have the full path in the data variable, so just display that and have the user select that file .
4. As you know, you cannot AJAX upload files via AJAX post, you will have to do a real html form submission. You can make this cleaner (for your users) using form.submit() for your image elements, but the code complexity seems more than what is useful since you (seemingly) only have 1 image you are uploading.